# What typeface is used on the name of cards in Hearthstone?

Tags: font-identification

What font is used for the card titles/names in Blizzard's Hearthstone game? Link to a sample: https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/File:Luna%27s_Pocket_Galaxy(89888).png

Comment: To be sure a similar question was asked on reddit but the user who asked it received no response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Belwe Bold from Letraset. Various digital versions from ITC, Adobe and others. Alan Meeks, one of the original designers, did a slightly less quirky redraw called Witchcraft adding a bold italic weight, and if you want the style at its quirkiest and swooshiest check out [Voyage](https://vj-type.com/family/voyage/) and Cako by VJ-Type.